# Houghlines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

After detecting the lines in an image using [Hough lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), how can I use it to calculate the change in angle (rotation) of the lines of a reference image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note to readers:** This is a follow-up question, refer to these for background:

- [How to select maximum intensity in Hough transform in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975206/how-to-select-maximum-intensity-in-hough-transform-in-matlab/1975261#1975261)
- [Calculating displacement moved in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062760/calculating-displacement-moved-in-matlab)

---

The process is similar to what I showed before. Below I am using [the images from your previous question](http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x11/veronicafmy/FYP/pict1.jpg) (since you provided only one, I created the other by rotating the first by 10 degrees).

We start by detecting the lines for the two images. We do this with the help of the [Hough](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html) [transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghpeaks.html). This what it looks like applied to both images:

[image: Images with detected lines and points order]

Next, we want to perform image registration using the line endpoints as control-points. First, we make sure the points correspond to each other in the two images. I do this by computing the convex hull using **[`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html)** which automatically sorts them in counterclockwise-order (or is it in the opposite direction!). The numbers shown above indicate the order.

Finally, we use the function **[`cp2tform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html)** to get the transformation matrix, which we use to align the images and extract the translation, rotation, and scaling.

The following is the complete code:

```
%% # Step 1: read and prepare images
%# (since you provided only one, I created the other by rotating the first).
I1 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se6zX.jpg');
I1 = rgb2gray( imcrop(I1, [85   35  445  345]) ); %# Get rid of white border
I2 = imrotate(I1, -10, 'bilinear', 'crop'); %# Create 2nd by rotating 10 degrees

%% # Step 2: detect the cross sign endpoints (sorted in same order)
p1 = getCross(I1);
p2 = getCross(I2);

%% # Step 3: perform Image Registration
%# Find transformation that maps I2 to I1 using the 4 control points for each
t = cp2tform(p2,p1,'affine');

%# Transform I2 to be aligned with I1
II2 = imtransform(I2, t, 'XData',[1 size(I1,2)], 'YData',[1 size(I1,1)]);

%# Plot
figure('menu','none')
subplot(131), imshow(I1), title('I1')
subplot(132), imshow(I2), title('I2')
subplot(133), imshow(II2), title('I2 (aligned)')

%# Recover affine transformation params (translation, rotation, scale)
ss = t.tdata.Tinv(2,1);
sc = t.tdata.Tinv(1,1);
tx = t.tdata.Tinv(3,1);
ty = t.tdata.Tinv(3,2);
scale = sqrt(ss*ss + sc*sc)
rotation = atan2(ss,sc)*180/pi
translation = [tx ty]
```

And here's the function that extract the lines endpoints:

```
function points = getCross(I)
    %# Get edges (simply by thresholding)
    I = imfilter(I, fspecial('gaussian', [7 7], 1), 'symmetric');
    BW = imclearborder(~im2bw(I, 0.5));

    %# Hough transform
    [H,T,R] = hough(BW);

    %# Detect peaks
    P  = houghpeaks(H, 2);

    %# Detect lines
    lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P);

    %# Sort 2D points in counterclockwise order
    points = [vertcat(lines.point1); vertcat(lines.point2)];
    idx = convhull(points(:,1), points(:,2));
    points = points(idx(1:end-1),:);
end
```

with the result:

[image: Resulting aligned image]

```
scale =
    1.0025
rotation =
   -9.7041
translation =
   32.5270  -38.5021
```

The rotation is recovered as almost 10 degrees (with some inevitable error), and scaling is effectively 1 (meaning there was no zooming). Note that there was a translation component in the above example, because rotation was not performed around the center of the cross sign).

Comment: Hello,

Would like to ask what does the numbers for the translation mean? The number of pixels moved? I tried to zoom in to the pixel level and calculate the pixels moved but it does not tally. Thanks. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: After doing the image registration part, we end up with the affine transformation matrix, from which we extract the rotation and translation. Now as I mentioned in the end, the translation must have happened in the process of creating the second image since the rotation is not with respect to the cross sign center.. Did you try to apply this process to your actual images? Besides, in this case we are ultimately only interested in the rotation part which we successfully recovered (-9.7 degrees, almost 10)!!

Comment: Hello, I did try this process on my actual images. As my images are also rotated such that it is not around the center of the cross sign, I would also need the translation of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) implementation of the Hough transform is, but the orientation of the line will be simply be at a right angle (90 degrees or pi/2 radians) to the angle you've used to identify the line in the first place.

I hope that helps. There's decent coverage of Hough transforms on the web and Wikipedia is a good place to start.